# Serialization not implemented?

Tags: java, serialization

What I understand is that I can implement `Serializable` interface to make my object serializable.

But I don't get where is `writeObject` method implemented when `Serializable` is an interface, so it doesn't contain implementation of methods, just a definition?

Comment: implementing Serializable is **just flagging** that a class can be Serialized. Ensuring all members are Serializable is the job of the compiler and process of Serialization is the job of the JRE (not sure if its the JVM or the JRE libs)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you already noticed, the *Serializable* is a Marker Interface and does not have any methods to implement. Implementing Serializable is just a note that this one is eligible for serialization which is handled using `ObjectOutputStream`.

Methods you mentioned need to be implemented in a class implementing the *Serializable* interface and will be picked up automatically. Since there is no obligation for implementing them, they are not included in the interface.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/platform/serialization/spec/serial-arch.html#a4539

Comment: Serialization is done *externally* to the JVM, by the `ObjectOutputStream` class.

Comment: Makes me wonder why this isn't changed in Java 1.8 using default methods. As it provides the functionality needed for this particular case.

Comment: @n247s you could only write to an ObjectOutputSTream and read from an ObjectInputStream with writeObject/readObject but you might not want to use that form of serialization, there is dozens of alternatives. There is no common marker interface for stream you can write objects to/read objects from

Comment: @EJP well, that was an unfortunate wording. I will improve my answer

Answer (score 1):

Tough all the answers posted so far are right, I wish to add some extra comments:

`java.io.Serializable` was already part of the Java 1.1 API (among the first versions of Java), and was meant as an **easy** way for the programmer to mark any class to have a special behaviour.

According to OOP principles, that should have been done through a **regular interface**, which is what you (and me, and any other programmer) would have expected. Something like this:

```
public interface Serializable<E>
{
    public E read(DataInput input) throws IOException;

    public void write(DataOutput output) throws IOException;
}
```

But, since there are many classes in Java which needed to be serialized, the Java Language designers wished to save troubles to programmers, by some kind of mechanism through which serialization would be performed automatically. But how?

- Through an abstract class? Nope. That would have prevented any custom class to have its own hierarchy (since in Java there is only **single** inheritance).
- Making `java.lang.Object` serializable? Neither so, because that would have prevented programmers to decide which class should be serializable and which should not.

On top of all, there was a hughe problem: Note that method `read` is supposed to **create** and return an object of class E from a DataInput stream. An abstract class just can not create instances of its subclasses whithout further information (the abstract class **does not know** which is the applied subclass).

So, they decided to pass over the OOP and offer Serialization as a **special non-oop feature** of the serialization classes ObjectOutputStream/ObjectInputStream (credits to EJP for this detail) in the form of a "dummy" interface recognizable by them, at the price of adding somehow some confussion to the class definitions, because an interface with no methods is **nonsense** (Same approach they adopted for `java.lang.Cloneable`).

Actually, it adds even more confussion, because custom serialization must be done by implementing **private** methods `readObject` and `writeObject` (as specified by [ObjectOutputStream](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/ObjectOutputStream.html)), which is a feature non describible in terms of a Java interface.

Nowadays, these kind of *marking* can be done through **annotations**. Well, think of `Serializable` as an interface which should have been an annotation, but still remains as an interface for those -endless- compatibility reasons.

Comment: `Serializable` is neither a 'language feature', 'reserved', nor 'recognizable by the JVM'. It is a contract between the class and `ObjectInputStream` and `ObjectOutputStream`.

Comment: A contract with no clauses? With no specified behaviour? Strange contract, indeeed.Anyway, you are right. I will correct that detail.

Comment: *"because an interface with no methods is nonsense"* ... according to Joshua Bloch (Effective Java, 2nd Ed.) there are situations in which marker interfaces may be preferred to annotations.

Comment: *"even more confussion, because custom serialization must be done by implementing private methods "* ... this is actually a good thing.  One of the confounding problems with the `Externalizable` interface (which extends Serializable) is that the custom serialization methods expressed by the interface have to be public ... even if you have no wish to make them part of your exported API.

Comment: @scottb Interesting. I haven't read the 2nd edition yet. Thanks for the comment.

Comment: @scottb "even if you have no wish to make them part of your exported API". In fact, you **do** wish to make Serializable part of your public API, because when you set your class as Serializable, you are willing that a third party serializes/parses your objects at any time. So, you are publishing a **usable behaviour**.

Comment: Let's be honest, my friends: Suppose Java does not have any serialization mechanism, and that someone here on SO proposes a solution based on an empty interface with client classes that rely upon assumed private methods through reflection. How many upvotes do you think it would collect???